# Data-TestID has multiple elements, Can i use a function to call out nth(1)

Tags: javascript, testing, integration-testing, playwright-test

there are multiple donut charts on my screen so i have two functions, donut chart progress and conut chart percentage. They both spit out the text value located inside each donut chart.

```
async function donutChartPercentage(page) {
  const donutChartPercentageText = await playerBioObject(page).donutChartLabel.nth(1).textContent();
  return donutChartPercentageText
}

async function donutChartProgress(page) {
  const inputElement = statisticsObject(page).donutChartCircleProgress.nth(1);
  const myText = await inputElement.getAttribute('stroke-dasharray');
  const progressText: string = (myText?.split(" ")[0])!;
  const progressNumber:number = parseFloat(progressText);
  const finalPercentageNumber = Math.round(progressNumber / 31.4 * 100);
  const finalPercentageNumberString = finalPercentageNumber.toString()
  return finalPercentageNumberString;
}
```

my question is how could i change that n number to work in parralel with my tests.

I currently call out the function like;...

```
expect(await donutChartProgress(page)+"%").toEqual(await donutChartPercentage(page));
```

```
expect(await donutChartProgress(page)+"%").toEqual(await donutChartPercentage(page));
```

im expecting something like

```
function donutChartPercentage (x: Number) {
 ...
donutChartCircleProgress.nth(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  async function donutChartProgress(page, x) {
  const nthNum = x
  const inputElement = statisticsObject(page).donutChartCircleProgress.nth(nthNum);
```

works a treat